# Constraints using If structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a data table and require some custom constraints. The data table is as following:

```
ID    int
Val_1 int
Val_2 int
Val_3 int
```

What i need is the following:

```
If (Val_1 == A)
{
    Val_2 cant be NULL;
} 
else if (Val_1 == B)
{
    Val_3 cant be NULL;
}
else if (Val_1 == C)
{
    Val_2 AND Val_3 cant be NULL;
}
else if (Val_1 == D)
{
    Val_2 OR Val_3 cant be NULL;
}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Can you convert the values to columns (single row)?

Comment: What happens if VAL_1 is not A, B, C, or D?

Comment: @Caramiriel in what way? Could you give an example?

Comment: @TheImpaler Nothing, seeing another constraint ensures that the value is always A,B,C or D (I simplified the example a bit to make it more readable so others might be able to get some use from the resulting answers)

Comment: @A.bakker The answer of TheImpaler is what I meant. Not sure if it suits your constraints, thats why I asked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that MySQL `CHECK` constraints are only enforced starting on MySQL 8.0.16. Before that, they are accepted and silently ignored.

Assuming you are using MySQL 8.0.16 or newer, you can do:

```
create table t (
  id varchar(1),
  val_1 int,
  val_2 int,
  val_3 int,
  constraint my_extra_constraint check (
    val_1 = 'A' and val_2 is not null or
    val_1 = 'B' and val_3 is not null or
    val_1 = 'C' and val_2 is not null and val_3 is not null or
    val_1 = 'D' and (val_2 is not null or val_3 is not null)
    or val_1 not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') -- remove this line if needed
  )
);
```

Comment: Looks good but aren't there more () required? On every line to be precise? or am i making a mistake here. (just like you encapsulated the "(val_2 is not null or val_3 is not null)" @ D.)

Comment: Ok, will try it out :) but still seems odd to me that the statements between the OR's at the end of the line doesn't need to be encapsulated

Comment: @A.bakker Ah, I see what you mean. In boolean logic the `AND` operator has higher precedence than the `OR` operator, so there's no need for extra parenthesis (except for case D). If it's not crystal clear to you, just add the parenthesis; it won't hurt.

Comment: It's clear, but i i think that with parenthesis it would be more readable :) correct answer nonetheless.

Comment: @A.bakker, You may like to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html